# Error deploy django 1.11 Admin sin estilos

Tags: python, django

Acabo de subir un proyecto de prueba en Django a *pythonanywhere*, en el cual estuve probando y me percate que no me cargan los archivos estáticos del admin.

He realizado las configuraciones correspondientes y aplique el comando `python manage.py collectstatic`, el cual creo una copia de los estilos del admin a la carpeta `static`. Revisando la pagina del admin me percate que se esta generando una doble ruta lo cual no permite encontrar el archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi archivo `settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for TicketsSys project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '&s$jlnj62vln9#v)t+kmp1&k$ay*f@7fzsch98p@_o5(4z*m^p'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['sockramx.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'tickets',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'TicketsSys.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'TicketsSys.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/sockramx/TicketsSys/static/"
```

Comment: En INSTALL_APPS tienes tickets al principio , entiendo que es una app tuya , prueba poniendo después de 'django.contrib.staticfiles', para que los static carguen antes de ejecutar la app

Answer (score 0):

En las settings tienes puesto más o menos lo siguiente

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/nombreUser/nombreProyecto/static'
```

pero además se tiene que agregar dentro de la configuración que te ofrece pythonanywhere a tu app, existe una parte llamada static files, como puedes ver a continuación

[image: Esto encontrarás en la conf de la app]

Además por otro lado puedes verificar que la ruta de la carpeta static sea correcta.

Saludos!